# SQL Query on how to select data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi All I have two tables

```
Table 1 

id details
1  abc
2  def
3  xyz

Table 2
id details 
1  rst
1  uvw
```

I need the result as below

```
1 abc
1 rst
1 uvw
```

Please help!

Comment: Describe why you want that result?

Comment: You appear not to like the obvious solutions given, so maybe you need to explain a bit more what sort of answer you seek?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.details
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.id, t2.details
FROM table2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t2.id = t1.id);
```

Comment: @stack - a set operator like UNION (ALL) is the only **sensible** way to get the result set you require from the tables you describe. There are plenty of exotic ways to produce this result set (e.g. a pipelined function). What is it about this solution that you don't like?

Comment: Thanks yogesh! i got the results i wanted your  approach!

Comment: @stack - if you found this answer useful please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the quality of StackOverflow as a resource for future Seekers.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, it could look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id=1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id=1;
```